# How to open unique, per-user instance of firefox in linux through command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, centos

In my team, multiple people use same account on linux based server. If one user already opened firefox and others try to open firefox, it the throws the following error:

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.

I need something like `$ spyder --new-instance` to create new instance of spyder.

OS : centOS 7

firefox version : Mozilla Firefox 68.4.1esr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From mozilla [website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) I found command line to open new instance, not a new window in running instance, which allows multiple copies of application to be open at a time. It is

`firefox -new-instance -P "Another Profile"`

Then create new profile > start firefox.

Note: It is not available for Windows